# Excel how to take characters in the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to return the characters after "OR XXXXXXXXXXXX" in the reference cell. Rather than using a RIGHT function, I think there is an way to set up an way with "LEN" functions. Here is what I have found so far-

Cell A2:

```
=IF(
ISERR(SEARCH("LUR",C2))=FALSE,
RIGHT(B2, 10),
C3)
```

[image: Screen Shot]

But this isn't work for Cell A2, A3 or so on. Is there any way I can extract only the characters after "OR" in Column B? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `RIGHT()`, but you make the second parameter based on the `LEN()` and `Find()` function:

```
=RIGHT(B2, LEN(B2) - FIND("OR", B2, 1)-1)
```

`FIND()` returns the starting position of the characters "OR" in `B2`. Substracting that from the length minus 1 more gets us to the right number of characters for the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks! Works Good as gold!